# Best way to display JSON (well formatted) in UITextView or UIWebView in iOS

Tags: ios, json

I need to display JSON in my iPhone app. Currently I am getting unformatted JSON - like one big string with no indentation.

What would be the best way to display this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 19, accepted):

to get formatted JSON string.

The solution is to create JSON Object from JSON string,

and then convert the JSON object back to JSON String, using `.PrettyPrinted` option.

The code is

```
let jsonString = "[{\"person\": {\"name\":\"Dani\",\"age\":\"24\"}},{\"person\": {\"name\":\"ray\",\"age\":\"70\"}}]"

var error: NSError?

//1. convert string to NSData
let jsonData = jsonString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!

//2. convert JSON data to JSON object
let jsonObject:AnyObject = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jsonData, options: nil, error: &error)!

//3. convert back to JSON data by setting .PrettyPrinted option
let prettyJsonData = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(jsonObject, options: .PrettyPrinted, error: &error)!

//4. convert NSData back to NSString (use NSString init for convenience), later you can convert to String.
let prettyPrintedJson = NSString(data: prettyJsonData, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)!

//print the result
println("\(prettyPrintedJson)")
```

---

The result will look like this

[image: pretty printed JSON String]

Comment: @nRewik Why `NSString` & not `String`?

Answer (score 4):

Objective-C code

```
NSString *jsonString = @"[{\"person\": {\"name\":\"Dani\",\"age\":\"24\"}},{\"person\": {\"name\":\"ray\",\"age\":\"70\"}}]";
NSData *jsonData = [jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
id jsonObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:nil error:&error];
NSData *prettyJsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:jsonObject options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];
NSString *prettyPrintedJson = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[prettyJsonData bytes]];

NSLog(@"%@", prettyPrintedJson);
```

Answer (score 1):

here's the Objective-C code.

---

> NSString+PrettyPrint.h

```
@interface NSString (PrettyPrint)

+ (NSString * _Nonnull)prettifiedJsonStringFromData:(nullable NSData *)data;
+ (NSString * _Nonnull)prettifiedStringFromDictionary:(nullable NSDictionary *)dictionary;

@end
```

---

> NSString+PrettyPrint.m

```
#import "NSString+PrettyPrint.h"

@implementation NSString (PrettyPrint)

+ (NSString *)prettifiedStringFromDictionary:(nullable NSDictionary *)dictionary {
    
    if (dictionary == nil) { return @"nil"; }
    
    NSMutableString *returnStr = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@"[ \n"];
    
    for (NSString *key in dictionary) {
        [returnStr appendFormat:@"  %@: %@,\n", key, [dictionary valueForKey:key]];
    }

    [returnStr appendFormat:@"]"];

    return returnStr;
}

+ (NSString *)prettifiedJsonStringFromData:(nullable NSData *)data {
    
    if (data == nil) { return @"nil"; }
    
    NSData *jsonData;
    NSError *error = nil;
    
    NSString *jsonStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    jsonData = [jsonStr dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    id jsonObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error];
    if (jsonObject == nil) {
        return @"nil (json object from data)";
    } else {
        BOOL isValidJsonObject = [NSJSONSerialization isValidJSONObject:jsonObject];
        if (isValidJsonObject) {
            NSData *finalData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:jsonObject options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];
            //TODO: error description
            NSString *prettyJson = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:finalData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            return prettyJson;
        } else {
            return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n%@", jsonStr, @" (⚠️ Invalid json object ⚠️)\n"];
        }
    }
}

@end
```

---

then call methods when u need to use them.

ex1. Print NSData for body, response ...etc

```
NSLog(@"body: %@", [NSString prettifiedJsonStringFromData:[request HTTPBody]]);
```

ex2. Print NSDictionary

```
NSLog(@"headers: %@", [NSString prettifiedStringFromDictionary:[request allHTTPHeaderFields]]);
```

---

Probably you'll get these results in log.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Bear in mind, if you are dealing with `Encodable` objects you can use `JSONEncoder` for pretty printing.

```
let encoder = JSONEncoder()
encoder.outputFormatting = .prettyPrinted
        
guard let jsonData = try? encoder.encode(obj) else {
    return
}
        
let text = String(decoding: jsonData, as: UTF8.self)
```